# According to valgrind, malloc and new have a huge share in overall costs. How can I reduce that?

Tags: c++, performance, malloc, valgrind, new-operator

When I profile my program I get these results (see lower half):
[image]

Functions that I wrote seams to take about the right amount of costs. But I don't know why `operator new`, `malloc`and even `operator delete` as well as `free` are so expensive.

For example `Cabin(const&)`: it copies a couple of things - including four small vectors:

```
Cabin::Cabin(const Cabin& c)
    : m_entrance(c.m_entrance),           //just 3 int's on the stack
      m_seatContainer(c.m_seatContainer), //vector of 120 objects
      m_rows(c.m_rows),                   //vector of 20 int's
      m_cols(c.m_cols)                    //vector of 6 int's
{
    m_seats.reserve(c.m_seats.size());
    for(auto& s : m_seatContainer)
        m_seats.emplace_back(&s);         //vector of 120 pointers
}
```

The valgrind output for `Cabin(const&)` looks like this:
[image]

Is it normal for `new` and `malloc` to take so much time? What more information is needed? Also I'm not to much familiar with valgrind and profiling in general.

Comment: The number of calls to the copy c'tor and the number of calls to `operator new` do not correlate. Try to get a cumulative view of the spend CPU time and look for numbers that look unreasonable.

Comment: Why are you posting the code for `Cabin::Cabin` when the obvious offenders are `BoardingDDalgo::board()` and `main._omp_fn.0` ? The former is consuming 50.1% of all the CPU time, callers included, and the latter is consuming 29.5% of the CPU time on its own. That strongly suggets that the `new` calls are in `BoardingDDalgo::board()`

Comment: @MSalters because `Cabin::Cabin` seams to be unreasonable. My problem is the about of new calls and not the cost of `board()`. The latter is expensive - I know that. But the first should not be (at least not that much).

Comment: How is Cabin's ctor unreasonable? It's being called 1.1 million times! No wonder that adds up. As do 6 million calls to `new`. But just 8 calls which together take 29.5%, that's a _lot_.

Comment: The ctor is called 3887 times. And then calls new 1 million times. This makes no sense when you check what it is actually doing. If i misinterpret the graphs tell me.

Comment: The comments in your constructor indicate that all those vectors have fixed sizes.  If that's the case, why not use arrays instead?  It also appears from your profiling that you are doing a lot of copying.  Perhaps you're passing things by value when you didn't mean to.  Depending on your program, you may get substantial benefits from _move semantics_.

Comment: Your code is making copies of objects , many more than is necessary.  If you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  that also shows the anomalous profiling then we can advise on how to reduce this.

Comment: @dani sort the bottom pane by "called" - show how many times `Cabin::Cabin(const Cabin& c)` is called   (and it might show up some other interesting info)

Answer (score 2):

You should look not just at the percentage of time spent, but also the number of calls column. And I see six million calls to `operator new`. Well, what did you expect, from that?

This is typically what happens when either the wrong container, or the wrong algorithm gets used. Let's take a look at the small code snippet you showed.

It initializes a vector in a loop that invokes `emplace_back()`. Well, if that's how you initialize a vector of a moderate-to-large size, you can expect the entire process to involve a series of repeated allocations and reallocations, as the vector grows in size, with each `emplace_back()/push_back()` call. Not to mention the addition CPU cycles burned moving the partially-grown vector from one buffer to another, each time the vector goes on a growth spurt.

To do this smartly, use `reserve()` once, to reserve sufficient amount of entries in the vector for the elements you are about to `emplace_back()` or `push_back()`. Just one allocation call. You state that this vector is expected to be initialized with a hundred, or so pointers. Most vector implementatins grow the internal vector buffer logarithmically, so that's six or seven allocations. So using `reserve()`, strategically, should result in one sixths the number of calls to operator new, at this point.

The other thing that the constructor is doing is copying several vectors. This shouldn't take a lot of time, but you also have to ask yourself, is this really necessary in the first place. Perhaps it's sufficient to put all these vectors in a `std::shared_ptr`-managed reference-counted object, so the only thing that happens here is a pointer copy and a reference count increment, rather than allocating a bunch of new vectors. This is something that only you would know the answer to.

Allocating a buffer for four new vectors, doesn't seem like much. But when you've profiled six millions calls to `operator new`, and if this is a hot code path, and your profile run indicates this is where you're burning up all your time, then getting rid of even a few unneeded buffer allocations could make quite a bit of a difference.

Comment: I'm using reserve. The other vectors in the initialization list are copy constructed. Hence per copy of Cabin there are 4 allocations. The c'tor is called 3778 times. Each call causing 4 allocations means about 15000 calls to new and not 1.1 millions as given in the picture.

Comment: Vector is required to use geometric reallocation, so you should expect lg n reallocations, not one for each call to emplace_back.

Comment: The code in the question already does do exactly what you recommend in the fourth paragraph.

Comment: @BillyONeal The `reserve` function allows you to specify 1 reallocation

Comment: @M.M: Sure; the problem with reserve is that half the times I see it used people don't know what they're doing and trigger quadradic complexity. Nothing going on with vector here explains 6 million new calls.

Answer (score 2):

As the top half shows, the `Cabin` *copy* ctor is called a million times. You may have only 3778 "real" Cabin objects, but you're passing them around by value as if copies are free.

That said, since `m_rows` contains 20 ints and `m_cols` contains 6 ints, you should be using `std::array<>`. Even for the 120 pointers that may be a better choice.

Comment: `ctor` calls `new` 1 million times. `ctor`is called 3778 times. I don't pass `Cabin`around by value. I make exactly 3778 copies and each is done by intent. In this example the dimensions of the members are fixed. But that is determined at the start of the program. As far as I know array needs a fixed size at compiling.